# Vowel in "раст\рос" stem: how did it happen that they are different?

Tags: этимология, правописание

The following words have the same stem:

> рост
>   росток
>   рослый
>   растение
>   расти
>   возрасти
>   возросший
>   возраст

I think that they have the same stem because their meaning is related and they sound similar or are even formed one from another in the same way other similar words are formed (*возрасти* - *возросший*, *восходить* - *восшедший*).

**My question is**: how did it happen that they have different vowels in their stems, sometimes *о* and sometimes *а*?

As it was explained in school, "if there is a *т* after *с*, write *a*, otherwise write *о*" + a bunch of exceptions, as usual the Russian grammar. Though being nice as a heuristic to learn the spelling, this rule has no explanatory power. I would like to know how did it happen that the vowels are different.

Answer (score 4):

Linguists believe that this very vowel alternation is due to mainly two reasons: Church Slavonic influence and lack of strong stress in Old Russian. (After a bit of thinking we can even claim that actually those two reasons are related, though nevertheless are different.)

In Church Slavonic there was a verb "[расти](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0545.htm)" and noun "растъ". If you look in modern Bulgarian or Serbian and some other Slavonic languages (and some of them historically experienced Church Slavonic influence as well) you'll find exactly this word, "раст".

In Old Russian the root was "рост". But, once again, on early stage of Russian language evolution this difference was not that dramatic. That means that in written form both "а" and "о" root forms had been used. It it not only about **рост/раст**, for example **ровно/равно** pair shares the same reasons of existence: first root is Old Russian and second one is Church Slavonic.

Finally, things got even more complicated when in Moscow dialect with it well-known vowel о/а шифт (which is now a pronunciation norm) overcame other dialects.

By the way, there are some other roots with **a/o** alternation (коснуться/касаться, полагать/положить, плавник/пловец, выскочка/cкакун, творец/тварь etc.). Some of this forms exists because two above-mentioned reasons, some of them share even more complicated and old reasons, having their origins in PIE language, which embraced [apophony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophony) (i.e. alternation of sounds for indicating grammatical information) pretty much - and this apophonic features hadn't gone without a trace in Russian as well.

A final note: As for the mnemonic rule you've provided, it worth to mention that there are two exclusions: **росток**, **ростовщик** and **отрасль**. As for mentioned in  other answer **Ростов** and **Ростислав**, it is not that easy, there's no clear evidence that Рост in Ростов is related to slavic root, so this is still disputable.

Answer (score 2):

This duality has appeared due to the wide use of Church Slavonic (Old Bulgarian) language in Ancient Rus. The vowel 'a' came exactly from Old Bulgarian, as well as lots of other loans that still have a great influence in modern Russian language (even in pronunciation, i.e. using a voiced glottal fricative '*g*' in '*бог*'). The roots of this duality are not that vivid, so you do not need to bother about the etymology, just know the rules (as nobody bothers today about the fact that English article '*the*' has masculine gender ages ago).

Answer (score 1):

When a vowel is stressed, it will be obviously O or A, as рОст.
in other cases (when a vowel is unstressed) the rule is enough simple

before CТ and Щ is А, the rest is О (exceptions: росток, ростовщик, Ростов, отрасль, Ростислав  and their derivatives)

Comment: I know the heuristic rule, this is not my question. My question was why did it happen.